# transforma archivo a diccionario y obtener ciertos elementos (Python)

Tags: python

El problema es el siguiente:
Programe la función "guaguas_n_anio(archivo)"  que
recibe el archivo "1920-2020_final.csv"  y retorna un diccionario donde la llave
corresponde al año y el valor al número de guaguas registradas para ese año.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esa es la imagen de la estructura de la tabla, existen mas de 50 columnas con datos

```
import csv

d={}

def guaguas_n_anio(archivo):
    with open(f'{archivo}', 'r') as file:

     reader = csv.reader(file)
     next(reader) # Descartamos cabecera
     nuevo_dict = dict(reader)
     print(reader)
```

He probado distintas cosas pero no me funciona transforma el archivo a diccionario, ademas las llaves tampoco me funcionan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una solución:

```
def guaguas_n_anio(archivo):
    d = defaultdict(int)
    with open(archivo, 'r') as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        next(reader)  # Descartamos cabecera
        for annio, nombre, sexo, numero in reader:
            d[annio] += int(numero)
    return d
```

Esta función recibe el nombre del archivo y retorna un diccionario con llave año y valor igual al total de nacimientos (hombre, mujeres y otros) del año.

La función abre el archivo .csv, descarta el header y a continuación procesa cada línea de datos. De cada línea se extraen las columnas, de las cuales solo nos interesa el año y número.

Para totalizar usamos `defaultdict`, que es un diccionario que se inicializa automáticamente cuando no existe la llave. En este caso dijimos que el diccionario contiene `int`, por que los valores se inicializan automáticamente en cero.

Ahora, si cada línea contiene muchos datos, puedes mejor leer la linea en una lista y sacar por indice el año y el número:

```
    for datos in reader:
        annio = datos[0]
        numero = datos[3]
        d[annio] += int(numero)
```

#### Demo

*nac.csv*

```
ano,nombre,sexo,n
2000,Juan,m,10
2000,Maria,f,3
2001,Juan,m,5
2001,Maria,f,6
```

*código*

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

def guaguas_n_anio(archivo):
    d = defaultdict(int)
    with open(archivo, 'r') as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file)
        next(reader)  # Descartamos cabecera
        for annio, nombre, sexo, numero in reader:
            d[annio] += int(numero)
    return d

nac = guaguas_n_anio("nac.csv")
for ano, numero in nac.items():
    print(f"Año {ano} Nac {numero}")
```

produce:

```
Año 2000 Nac 13
Año 2001 Nac 11

Process finished with exit code 0
```